# How to round the floating piont values of textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have textboxes on my form using for txtDueAmount, txtPaidamount, txtDiscount and txtNetBalance. Every time I want that as I press the save button so all the floating point values of textboxes turns into integer and if any value is like 30.5 so it also converters it into 31.

This is my insert query:

```
Insert("SaleMaster", "SaleID, SaleTotalAmount, SalePaidAmount, SaleDiscount,
SaleNetBalance, SaleDate", txtSaleID.Text & ", " & txtSaleDueAmount.Text & 
", " & txtSalePaidAmount.Text & ", " & txtSaleDiscount.Text & ", " & 
txtSaleNetBal.Text & ", '" & dtpSale.Value.Date & "'")
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: What is the type of the DB columns?  By the way, this looks ripe for SQL injection attacks.  I would be much better to use SQL parameters.

Comment: you have no code to convert text to numeric at all, let alone rounding.  Also meet [Little Bobby Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/1070452)

Comment: Db column type is integer

Comment: Integer doesn't support fractions, so it's the DB engine that's doing the rounding/truncation.  You need to use a column type which supports fractions/floating point values.

Comment: Doggart, you mean numeric or Float? Which one i am suppose to use?

Comment: Well, that all depends on the database engine.  Is this SQL Server, Jet DB, something else?

Comment: I strongly suggest you change your approach at saving. You should use SQL Parameters.

Comment: @The-Lotus, I've using parameterized queries for long time but i came across with a problem where parameterized query wasn't working. Thats why i changed the way to straight query. It wasn't working with my function.

Answer (score 0):

Just covert to integer using `CInt(txtbox.Text)`

You should also validate that the textboxs only have numeric values.

Comment: Also you may end up due to rounding that your figures do not add up.

Comment: What is that mean Mych, that ""Also you may end up due to rounding that your figures do not add up."".

Comment: he is saying that if you round the values used to produce a sum (TotalSale), then they will no longer add up.  In most cases you will want a float for those db columns so you do not have to round.  Do that after you switch to parameters

Comment: Yes... as Plutonix says.. Eg. 10.7 + 8.9 + 13.9 = 33.5 yet 10 + 8 +13 = 31

Comment: Dear plutonix, so should i simply change the DB column types for these fields??

Comment: I would... You can always restrict number of decimals if required.